# Bing WPF Pushpin control cuts off Content

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, bing-maps

**Attempt at option 1**

How can I make the content of the pushpin overflow the pushpin Icon.  It seems I can only display very small text which fits within the pushpin.  I have tried simply setting the content value as text, creating a TextBlock and setting the TextBlock as the content but all yield the same result.

```
pushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
pushpin.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
TextBlock ppContent = new TextBlock();
//ppContent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;
ppContent.Text = "heyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy";
ppContent.Width = 333;
ppContent.Height = 333;
pushpin.Content = ppContent ;
pushpin.Tag = pinLabel;
pushpin.Location = location;
```

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the text is cut off!

**Attempt at option 2**

Another route I tried was to define a `ControlTemplate`.  I can successfully get the ControlTemplate to display a new icon no problem by defining a `ControlTemplate` in the `Application.Resources`:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushPinTemplate">
        <Grid>

            <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding  Content}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
            <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Margin="0 35 0 0">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/DragHandleWhite.gif"/>

                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

and applying the template like so;

```
pushpin.Template = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["PushPinTemplate"];
```

The problem with this now becomes, that I can not access `textBlock1` from code behind to set the value to "heyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy".

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For option two:  change the Text binding for your TextBlock to

```
Text="{TemplateBinding  Content}"
```

Then just change the Content property of the pushpin to change the text.

Edit:
Make sure your ControlTemplate has the correct TargetType set.  In your case it should be Pushpin.  In your XAML, with your other namespace mappings (where it says xmlns) you need to add:

```
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF";assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
```

then your TargetType should be

```
TargetType="maps:Pushpin"
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the error: Error 1 Cannot find the static member 'ContentProperty' on the type 'Control'.

Comment: Edited my answer.  I believe you need to set the TargetType on your ControlTemplate

Comment: I assume it would be pushpin, but when I set that as the type, i get The type reference cannot find a public type named 'pushpin'

Comment: make sure you add whatever you mapped the namespace to.  look at my answer for an example.  your name could/will be different than mine

Comment: I added reference to a dll called "Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF" but when I try "Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin" it wont compile. Says cannot find public type named 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin'

Comment: you need to add a namespace mapping to your xaml to use functionality from that namespace in xaml.  Edited my answer again.

Comment: You are the best... I have been banging my head forever. Need to brush up on my end >.<